# fazer um botão de submit desse tipo

Tags: html, css, css3

Estou tentando reproduzir sites para estudar um pouco de html e css, tenho o seguinte codigo:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#back {
    background-image: url("back2.png");
    background-size: cover;

}

body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

#div_princ {
    background-color: white;
    width: 350px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
}

#loguin {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 35px;
    align-items: center;
   
}

.caixas_input {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background-color:#dcdde1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    border: transparent;
    
}
input:focus {
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
   outline: 0;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: black;
}

::placeholder{ 
    color: #a8a8a8;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#manter_login {
    position: absolute;
    top: 160px;
    left: 10px;
}

input[type=checkbox]{
    display:none; /* Esconde os inputs */
}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
    border: 1px transparent;
    content: "\00a0"; /** \\ 00a0, é um código hexadecimal para um espaço sem quebra **/
    display: inline-block;
    font: 16px/1em sans-serif;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 0 .25em 0 0;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius:4px;
    background-color: #dcdde1;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
    background: #e74c3c;
    color: #FFF;
    content: "\2713";
    text-align: center;
}

#rodape { 
    color: #a8a8a8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #a8a8a8;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


</head>
<body id="back">    
   <div id="div_princ">
        <div id="icon">
            <input type="image" src="icone.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="loguin">
            <h3>Insira Sua conta Riot</h3>
            <form>
                <label for="Loguin"></label>
                <input type="Loguin" placeholder="NOME DE USUARIO" class="caixas_input " required>  
                <label for="Password"></label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="SENHA" class="caixas_input " required>
                <br>
            <div id="manter_login">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="manterlogin"> 
                <label for="manterlogin">
                     <span style="color:#a8a8a8; font-weight: bold;">
                         Manter Loguin
                    </span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div id="rodape">
                <a href="https://signup.br.leagueoflegends.com/pt/signup/index#/">CRIAR CONTA</a> <br>
                <a href="https://recovery.riotgames.com/pt-br?region=BR1">NÃO CONSEGUE CRIAR CONTA ?</a> <br>
                <a>V9.0.0</a>
            </div>

            </form>
        </div>
   </div>

</body>

</html>
```

quero colocar um botão assim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

que quando tiver com o mouse sobre ele fique assim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: pra mim os 2 estão iguais... de qq forma, para mudar o style com o mouse sobre o elemento, use a pseudoclass `: hover`. Veja no seu codigo o exemplo do link `a:hover`

Comment: como seria para colocar a seta?

Comment: essa imagem é de um exemplo que peguei na net

Comment: Se o body é único na página, não faz sentido colocar um `id` nele.

Comment: Cara pelo que entendi você está tentando mudar a cor do botão quando passa o mouse em cima ou no click, existe um efeito chamado hover no css, da uma olhada nesse link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_animate_buttons.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com CSS você consegue fazer esse botão e a seta interna dele. Basta usar pseudo-elementos `::before` e `::after`. Um constrói a haste da seta e o outro a seta pra direita. Veja abaixo o código e comentários explicando o que cada propriedade faz. É possível ajustar cores e tamanhos como quiser.

No exemplo abaixo usei a tag `<a>`, mas você pode usar a tag `<button>` caso seja um botão de submit. Neste caso (se for usar `button`), você deve incluir mais duas propriedades: `all: unset;` (para remover estilos padrões do da tag button, como bordas, etc.) e `cursor: pointer;` (para aplicar o ícone de link no cursor do mouse, mas é opcional).

Veja:

```css
.botao{
   border-radius: 20px;
   width: 60px; /* largura do botão */
   height: 60px; /* altura do botão */
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   position: relative;
   background-color: #b22002; /* cor de fundo do botão */
}

/* haste da seta - */
.botao::before{
   content: '';
   height: 2px; /* altura */
   width: 20px; /* largura da haste */
   background-color: #fff; /* cor da haste. Deve ser igual à cor da seta */
   margin-left: -1px; /* afasta um pouco da esquerda para ajustar à seta */
   position: absolute;
}

/* seta pra direita > */
.botao::after{
   content: '';
   /* rotaciona a seta para ficar virada pra direita */
   -moz-transform: rotate(315deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(315deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
   transform: rotate(315deg);
   
   border-bottom-style: solid;
   border-bottom-width: 2px; /* largura da seta (parte de cima) */
   border-right-style: solid;
   border-right-width: 2px; /* largura da seta (parte de baixo) */
   /* height e width devem ter o mesmo valor */
   height: 12px; /* altura da seta */
   width: 12px; /* largura da seta */
   margin-left: 3px; /* desloca pra direita para ajustar */
   border-color: #fff; /* cor da seta */
}

.botao:hover{
   background-color: #841600; /* cor de fundo do botão quando passa o mouse */
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="botao"></a>
```

Comment: Muito bom, era exatamente isso que tava procurando, muito obrigado.

Comment: Se achou a resposta melhor e lhe atendeu, pode marcar ✔ nela.

Answer (score 1):

Não use uma div para fazer um `botton`, principalmente se vc não der semântica para ela usando `role` ou `aria-label`

Depois uma div não vai ter `type:submit` ou `type:button` vc vai ter que usar JS, depois ela não vai ser acessível por teclado usando `tab` (inclusive além do `:hover` trate tb o `:focus`)

Então use a tag `<button>` mesmo, e com CSS trate o elemento. Primeiro de um `all: unset` e depois coloque seus estilos como né exemplo abaixo

Outra coisa, para fazer a seta vc pode usar um artifício muito fácil que é um **`HTML  Entities`** tipo

## →

Aqui tem uma lista com uma infinidade de setas https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/arrows/

```css
button {
  all: unset;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: .5em;
  transition: background 500ms;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
button:focus,
button:hover {
  background: brown;
}
button::after {
  content: "\2192";
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit"></button>
```